# How to extract a substring beginning and ending with user defined special characters from a string in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, awk

I am working on linux scripts and want to extract a substring out of a master string as in the following example :-

Master string =

```
2011-12-03 11:04:22#Alex#Audrino^13b11254^Townville#USA#
```

What I require is :-

Substring =

```
13b11254
```

I simply want to read and extract whatever is there in between ^   ^ special characters.

This code will be used in a linux script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX sh compatible:

```
temp="${string#*^}"
printf "%s\n" "${temp%^*}"
```

Assumes that `^` is only used 2x per string as the 2 delimiters.

Comment: A little side note: you don't need to quote the parameter on the right side of the assignment statement as it's not subject to shell field splitting or glob expansion in this context. You are free to do it, of course, if you find that syntax more readable.

Comment: @Dimitre thanks - I am aware but it's just a personal habit/quirk of mine to always put strings in quotes - it's better than the other way around I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard shell *parameter expansion*:

```
% s='2011-12-03 11:04:22#Alex#Audrino^13b11254^Townville#USA#' ss=${s#*^} ss=${ss%^*}
% printf '%s\n' "$ss"                                                                  
13b11254
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , it explained syntax while jw013 showed the practical approach

Answer (score 1):

The solution bellow uses the `cut` utility, which spawns a process and is slower that the shell parameter expansion solution.  It might be easier to understand, and can be run on a file instead of on a single string.

```
s='2011-12-03 11:04:22#Alex#Audrino^13b11254^Townville#USA#'
echo $s | cut -d '^' -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bash arrays and field separator:

```
IFS="^"
s='2011-12-03 11:04:22#Alex#Audrino^13b11254^Townville#USA#'
array=($s)
echo ${array[1]}
```

This allows you to test is you have exactly 2 separators:

```
if [ ${#array[*]} -ne 3 ]
then
  echo error
else
  echo ok
fi
```